# React Native this.setState of text

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm new to React Native and I'm unable to get my variable to update when I change the value using this.setState(). On button click I am calling this function:

```
    const updateName = () => {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        user.updateProfile({
            displayName: "Test Test"
        }).then(function() {
            alert('Name changed')
        }).catch(function(e) {
            alert(e)
        })
        this.setState({ userFullName: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName })
    }
```

This updates the current user's display name to "Test Test" and I want this change to be reflected on the screen. It is currently being show in the userFullName variable, but I am getting a TypeError: undefined is not an object. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Its hard without all the code

Comment: what else do you need to see?

Answer (score 0):

If I were working on this I would write the function a bit more like this:

```js
const updateName = async (displayName) => {
    this.setState({ userFullName: displayName })
    try {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        await user.updateProfile({
            displayName
        })
        alert('Name changed')
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e)
        this.setState({ userFullName: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName })
    }
}
```

This doesn't answer why you're getting the `TypeError: undefined is not an object.` error, however, this will make sure that your UI is responsive while you are saving the new displayName.

Now, it's hard to tell what exactly the issue is with a generic error like that, but the variables I would check for being `undefined` would be `firebase`, `firebase.auth().currentUser`. Seems like that error could be referring to either of those variables since they are being accessed as objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get the same error in a Promise rejection

Comment: Does userFullName have to be a global variable, is that why the undefined error is occurring? Because I know the firebase part is not undefined

Comment: So I just realized you're using the class syntax for setting state instead of the hook syntax. If your React component is a class you need to remove the `const` before `updateName` so that your function is a class member function. This should make `this` bound to the correct thing. See if that changes anything.